# Increase Javascript Piano Performance

Tags: javascript, html

I made a small (like really small) [piano](http://codepen.io/Maharkus/pen/MjNLao) in Javascript/HTML, but the sound is delayed. Is there any way to optimize its performance?

Thanks for your help!

```
var c = new Audio("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37434025/PianoTones/piano_middle_C.mp3");

function playC() {
  var c2 = c.cloneNode();
  c2.play();
}

var d = new Audio("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37434025/PianoTones/piano_D.mp3");


function playD() {
  var d2 = d.cloneNode();
  d2.play();
}
```

Comment: For runnable code snippets, please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so **everything** is here on-site.

Comment: Gothdo is right. If you pre-clone the nodes, the only delay is the delay *inside* the sound data (which you'll also want to get rid of, it's a good fifth of a second long -- plenty long enough for a human to perceive).

Comment: Alright I'll try preloading the files. Thanks for your input, everybody.